# Cancel long-running TFDBatchMove while in progress

Tags: delphi

How can I cancel a batch move after calling [TFDBatchMove](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove).[Execute](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Execute), while it is still in progress? E.g. if the user presses a Cancel button on the form. I don't see any kind of Cancel method on TFDBatchMove.

I've tried using

```
  raise Exception.Create('Aborted');
```

in the OnProgress event of the TFDBatchMove (checking a Cancelled flag set by the Cancel button), but after pressing Ok on the exception message window, the batch move continues.

Another possibility is to just close the Reader component, or set `Reader := nil` in mid flight, but this seems like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the [**AbortJob**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.AbortJob) method. It's described like:

> Use the **AbortJob** method to stop the current data movement.
>
> After a call to **AbortJob**, the method stops reading data from the
>   reader data source, stops writing data to the writer and terminates
>   Execute method.

Comment: Ah - thank you!! Must be because it's the very first method listed in the docs, I missed it completely ;)